Solution of a second order linear elliptic P.D.E associated with the SUSY (Supersymmetric) Hamiltonian
I am considering supersymmetric Landau problem in a noncommutative plane in the light of deformation quantization. The background paper is here:https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.07192.pdf. The physical problem we consider is the system of a spin 1/2 charged particle with charge $e$ and mass $m$ placed in a noncommutative plane subjected to a vertical uniform magnetic field $B$. We have done the calculation for the ground state wave function of the associated SUSY Hamiltonian. When we were trying to solve the eigenvalue equations for the partner Hamiltonians in the excited states for any gauge parameter $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ (in the sense of the above-mentioned paper), we encountered a homogeneous linear elliptic partial differential equation of the second order in its canonical form: $$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial y^2}-\left(\frac{2i\gamma}{\alpha}\right)y\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}-\left[\frac{2i\gamma r}{\alpha(r-1)}\right] x\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}-\left[\frac{r^2\gamma^2}{\alpha^2(r-1)^2}\right]x^2\psi-\left(\frac{\gamma^2}{\alpha^2}\right)y^2\psi-\left(\frac{\rho}{\alpha^2}\right)\psi=0,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ depend on the physical constatnt $\hbar$, external magnetic field $B$, spatial noncommutativity parameter $\vartheta$, charge of the spin 1/2 particle $e$, and also on the gauge parameter $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$. Now, I want to solve for $\psi(x,y)$ with $\psi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dx\,dy)$.

I assume $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$?

Yes @MOMO. I want $\psi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dx,dy)\cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2}).$

Have you tried working with the equation in the form $(i\alpha\partial_x-\beta\partial_y+\gamma y+i\delta x)(i\alpha\partial_x+\beta\partial_y+\gamma y-i\delta x)\psi=-\rho\psi$?

@MOMO, any idea about how to proceed from the factorisation you suggested?

You can first solve the equation $(iα∂x+β∂y+γy−iδx)ψ=\lambda ψ$, and then check if there is a solution for some $\lambda$ such that $(iα∂x−β∂y+γy+iδx)ψ=−\frac{ρ}{\lambda}ψ$. This could lead to a family of solutions, although not the most general solution.

Another possible direction is to use Fourier transform.

@MOMO, the factorisation you suggested results in an additional term $(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma)\psi$ on the left side which is not in general zero.

Also, @MOMO, even if we try to move that term to the right side to redefine $\rho$, the first order operators you suggested in the factorisation do not seem to possess simultaneous eigenstates.
